# R and Hive Connection -RJDBC + RHive

Tags: java, r, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I have R and Hive on the same hostname, and I am trying to connect the two, so I can access Hive tables directly from R.  While I have been able to do so (using RHive), I am unable to connect with RJDBC.  I have two issues here, solving any of the two for now, would work with me.

**Issue1##**  Connection established between R and hive using RHIVE.  I ran a simple query,

```
rhive.query("CREATE TABLE test AS SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column1='ABC'")
```

This created the required table in the required database and run time wasn't much

```
test123<-rhive.query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column1='ABC'")
```

If I try to save the result in a temp object, test123, this query takes exceptionally 
long.

How do I resolve this and why would there be so much difference?  For example, test123 
takes 30+ mins and still doesn't complete, whereas the table "temp" takes < 1 minute

**Issue 2##**  I am unable to establish R and hive connection, using below.

```
require(RJDBC)
cp <- c(list.files("/location/lib/hadoop/lib", pattern = "[.]jar", full.names=TRUE, recursive=TRUE),
        list.files("/location/lib/hive/lib", pattern = "[.]jar", full.names=TRUE, recursive=TRUE), recursive=TRUE))
drv <- JDBC(driverClass = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver", classPath = cp)

hiveconnection <- dbConnect(drv,"jdbc:hive://hostname.com:10000/default", "username", "password")
```

Note:  the jar files are the same, RHive or RJDBC, however, I get the below warning and Putty hangs post that.  When using RHive, I get the same warning, but it goes further to establish the connection.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.6.0-1.cdh4.6.0.p0.26/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.6.0-1.cdh4.6.0.p0.26/lib/hive/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks a lot!

Comment: for issue #1, are you able to see anything in the Hive log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the second issue using this -

Change 1:

Adding hadoop-core .jar files, they were missing

Change 2:
drv <- JDBC(driverClass = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver", classPath = cp)

Change 3:  Updating the connection url to "jdbc:hive2://hostname:port/default"